# react-hook-form validation before submission

Tags: material-ui, react-hook-form

I have a form (sorry it is so long) that is very simple for a user to enter name, email, phone, comments:

```
    <form
        className={classes.root}
        data-testid="getting-started-form"
        onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}
    >
        <div style={{ width: '400px' }}>
            <div style={{ width: '100%'}}>
                <Controller as={<TextField
                    label="Name"
                    id="name"
                    name="name"
                    type="text"
                    value={name}
                    placeholder="Name"
                    onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>) => {
                        let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
                        setName(target.value);
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                        'data-testid': 'name'
                    }}
                />} name="name" rules={{ required: true }} control={control}
                />
                {errors.name && <span>Name is required</span>}
            </div>
            <div style={{ width: '100%' }}>
                <Controller as={<TextField
                    label="Email"
                    id="email"
                    name="email"
                    type="text"
                    value={email}
                    placeholder="Email"
                    style={{ width: '100%' }}
                    onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>) => {
                        let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
                        setEmail(target.value);
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                        'data-testid': 'email'
                    }}
                />} name="email" rules={{ required: true, pattern: /^\w+[\w-\.]*\@\w+((-\w+)|(\w*))\.[a-z]{2,3}$/i }} control={control}
                />
                {errors.email && <span>Email is required</span>}
            </div>
            <div style={{ width: '30%' }}>
                <Controller as={<TextField
                    label="Phone"
                    id="phone"
                    name="phone"
                    type="text"
                    value={phone}
                    placeholder="eg.15556667890"
                    onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>) => {
                        let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
                        setPhone(target.value);
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                        'data-testid': 'phone'
                    }}
                />} name="phone" rules={{ pattern: /\d{11}/ }} control={control}
                />
            </div>
            <div style={{ width: '30%' }}>
                <Controller as={<TextField
                    label="Comments"
                    id="comments"
                    name="comments"
                    type="text"
                    value={comments}
                    placeholder="Comments"
                    rows={6}
                    multiline
                    onChange={(e: React.FormEvent<EventTarget>) => {
                        let target = e.target as HTMLInputElement;
                        setComments(target.value);
                    }}
                    inputProps={{
                        'data-testid': 'comments'
                    }}
                />} name="comments" control={control}
                />
            </div>
        </div>
        <Button
            type="submit"
            aria-label="submit getting-started-form"
            variant="contained"
            color="primary"
            data-testid="getting-started-form-submit-button"
        >
            Submit
        </Button>
    </form>
```

All fields are validated on submission. Is there anyway to get react-hook-forms to do some kind of validation BEFORE the form is submitted? I would want flags like Angular has for dirty, pristine, etc.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Updated!
Validator API: https://react-hook-form.com/api/.

You can choose the value `onBlur` instead of default `onSubmit` mode.

You can follow the official docs here: https://react-hook-form.com/get-started#Registerfields.

Basically you need to `register` fields to be validated. And then `react-hook-form` will auto validate for you on submit.

Comment: First, the validation happens successfully on submit. What I want is for the validation to happen BEFORE submission. I think I have found one clue. If I enter an invalid field and submit the form validation happens as expected. From then on validation happens also BEFORE submission as I desired. However, if I enter an invalid field and simply change focus (tab to another field) validation does not happen. The `Controller` (part of the `react-hook-form`  package) component handles the `register` for me.

Comment: @KevinBurton did you found a solution for the behaviour you described? I am also facing exactly similar issue. Thanks

Comment: @AshishSaini I have not found a solution yet. Let me know if you find something.

Comment: @KevinBurton, sorry for the late reply. Can you take a look here: https://react-hook-form.com/api/.

They offer a `mode`, you can give value `onBlur` for that validation. Updated my answer also.

Comment: Yeah I made it working. I used `useForm({mode: 'all'})` to make it work. Thanks anyways.

Comment: Thanks so much! Using the attribute 'mode' was the thing!

Comment: @AshishSaini your suggestion works! Thanks.

Comment: @AshishSaini, great it works but even on field when in focus then you out focus on them it triggers the validation. My suggestion is use mode: "onChange" to trigger validation only on input value change

Comment: Updated link to the docs mentioned here: [react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#mode](https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform#mode); + thank you for the answer!

Answer (score 15):

Using **mode** we can do this:

**mode: onChange | onBlur | onSubmit | onTouched | all = 'onSubmit'** (React Native: compatible with Controller)

```
const { register, trigger, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    mode: 'all', // THIS WILL ALLOW ALL-TIME VALIDATION (May have performance impact)
    resolver: yupResolver(ValidationSchema),
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set `useForm({mode: "onChange"})` to trigger real time validation ONLY when the input value changes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your submit button disabled or want validation to trigger when input field changes then just do...

```
useForm({mode: 'all'})
```

with the useForm hook the validation happens immediately.

Answer (score 0):

To validate before submit you can use `Controller` component, inside you use `rules` prop, like this:

```js
<Controller
      name="name"
      control={control}
      defaultValue=""
      rules={{
          required: getRequired(t),
          validate: getValidation(t)          // <== Here you use validate
      }}
      render={({ onChange, onBlur, value }) => (
           <TextField
               error={Boolean(errors?.name)}
               helperText={errors?.name?.message}
               ...
            />
         )}
       />
```

Check official documentation example for [Controller](https://codesandbox.io/s/controller-rules-ipynf)

[image: official doc example]

Answer (score 0):

I think a lot of these solutions can be annoying for the user if they are in the process of submitting a valid answer but it keeps flagging it as invalid onChange.  I think the trigger validation function might be the most versatile:  https://react-hook-form.com/docs/useform/trigger

Especially if you have multiple views in your form, it will make things a lot easier.